# SwiftUI, how to make the background color animate multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI project that includes a Text object with a .onTapGesture working that, when triggered, should cause the button's background color to pop to another color then quickly fade back to the original color. In my code, I'm able to trigger the color pop, but it stays that way and won't fade back. I'm kind of at a loss on what to do, any help is appreciated...here is the code I'm using:

```
@State var buttonFlash = false


var body: some View {
    Text("Hello")
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .background(buttonFlash ? Color.white : Color.red)
        .animation(nil)
        .background(Color.red)
        .animation((Animation.linear).delay(0.1))
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Tapped!")
            self.buttonFlash.toggle()

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should cause the button's background color to pop to another color then quickly fade back to the original color.

You need to declare a function for that. Here is a possible approach for it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var buttonFlash: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .background(buttonFlash ? Color.white : Color.red)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tapped!")
                self.colorChange()
            }
    }
    
    private func colorChange() {
        // first toggle makes it red
        self.buttonFlash.toggle()
        
        // wait for 1 second
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
            // Back to normal with ease animation
            withAnimation(.easeIn){
                self.buttonFlash.toggle()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

It calls the method once tapped. This then triggers the color change and reverses it after 1 second.

Produces this outcome:

[image]

Comment: this is almost there, but the animation still doesn't quite work right...is it able to be customized as far as the easing? I tried removing the 2nd set of .background and .animation and setting the ease of the first animation to .easeOut, but it still eases in both directions...

Comment: Not sure if I can follow on what you want. 1) You want it to ease out when pressed. But then snap back to the original color without animation? 2) Or you want it to snap to a color when pressed and then ease out back to the original color?

Comment: #2 - snap to color when pressed then ease out back to original color

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to add the withAnimation in...I keep forgetting the effects of boolean toggles can be animated...thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to flash the `backgroundColor` multiple number of times. Use a method and loop over until a condition is met. Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var buttonFlash: Bool = false
    @State private var numberOfTimes = 6

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .background(buttonFlash ? Color.white : Color.red)
            .animation(nil)
            .background(Color.red)
            .animation((Animation.linear).delay(0.1))
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tapped!")
                self.animate()
            }
    }

    private func animate() {
        self.buttonFlash.toggle()
        if numberOfTimes > 0 {
            numberOfTimes -= 1
        } else {
            numberOfTimes = 6
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
            self.animate()
        })
    }
}
```