# SwiftUI, background color of view is white when transitioning with animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ZStack, with background color set to orange and ignores safe area. All subsequent views or previous views that it will navigate to will also have color that is NOT white.

Each individual view is embedded into a navigation view except the parent ZStack. When transitioning, using .easeInOut animation, the background shows a white color and the current view is shrinking. How do I set the color of that view or get rid of that white screen beneath it?

```
  ZStack{
            ColorFunctionIgnoreEdges()
            switch self.VM.ABC {
                case .A:
                    NavigationView{
                        
                        A(A: self.VM).animation(.default)
                           
                    }
                case .B:
                    NavigationView{
                        B(B: self.VM).animation(.none)
                         
                    }
                case .C:
                    NavigationView{
                        CView(C: self.VM).animation(.none)
                    }
                case .initlizing:
                    VStack{
                        Text("One sec...")
                        ProgressView()
                    }
            }
         
           
        }
```

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864753/swiftui-how-to-make-the-background-color-animate-multiple-times) one?

Comment: @Luffy , no, not in my case, it would still look very irregular with color fading to white.